# iOS/Swift: mapView won't update coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm having an issue with updating/refreshing the map.
The code below is from the MainViewController

```
let forecastConstants = ForecastConstants(apiKey: forecastAPIKey)
    coordinates.latitude = latPassed
    coordinates.longitude = LongPassed

if latPassed == 0 && LongPassed == 0 {
    coordinates.latitude = 43.161030
    coordinates.longitude = -77.610922
    }
```

LatPassed and LongPassed are passed from another controller (LocationViewController), where a new location (Lat and Long) is entered. All Controllers are in embedded in TabBar.

In MapViewController, I have:

```
var coordinate = MainForecastViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
let lat = coordinate.coordinates.latitude
let lon = coordinate.coordinates.longitude
}   

mapView.delegate = self
let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 1000, 1000)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
pin = AnnotationPin(title: "Load temp here", subtitle: "", coordinate: coord)
mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
mapView.selectAnnotation(pin, animated: true)

}
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: pin, reuseIdentifier: "forecast")
    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "weatherMapIcon")
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
    annotationView.transform = transform
    return annotationView
}
```

The problem is, when I enter a new location, it is updated in the main controller, but when I switch to MapViewController, the pin is still pinned to the default lat and long (43.161030, -77.610922). Am I doing this right and just need to update/refresh the mapView/Pin, or is there another approach to this?

Thanks you advance!

UPDATE:
Here is the MainViewController:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

  var latPassed = Double()
  var LongPassed = Double()
  // These are passed from LocationViewController
  var coordinates: (latitude: Double, longitude: Double) = (43.161030,-77.610922)
  // These are the default coordinates

func loadWeatherTemp() {
        let forecastConstants = ForecastConstants(apiKey: forecastAPIKey)
        coordinates.latitude = latPassed
        coordinates.longitude = LongPassed

        if latPassed == 0 && LongPassed == 0 {
            coordinates.latitude = 43.161030
            coordinates.longitude = -77.610922
        }
        forecastConstants.getForecast(latitude: coordinates.latitude, longitude: coordinates.longitude) { (currentWeather) in
            if let currentWeather = currentWeather {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // stuff
                }
            }
        }
// more stuff
}
```

Comment: try to add ( ) in you if "if latPassed == 0 && LongPassed == 0 {" should be "if ((latPassed == 0) && (LongPassed == 0)) { "

Comment: do u debug and chk in mapviewcontroller lat and lon are available

Comment: Use `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`

Comment: () in if statement, and viewDidAppear didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to have a coordinate object to have in MapViewController() and set the new coordinates from MainViewController(). I'm telling Something like below:

MapViewController.swift

```
var newCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D() {
   didSet {
     let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newCoordinates, 1000, 1000)
     mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
     pin = AnnotationPin(title: "Load temp here", subtitle: "", coordinate: coord)
     mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
     mapView.selectAnnotation(pin, animated: true)
   }
```

UPDATE: -
MainViewController.swift

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
  var latPassed = Double()
  var LongPassed = Double()
  weak var mapVC = MapViewController()//this will be your mapvc which is loaded in your tabbar.
  var coordinates: (latitude: Double, longitude: Double) = (43.161030,-77.610922) {
     didSet {
         mapVC.newCoordinates = self.coordinates // Every time you update your coordinates here, send that coordinate to MapViewController() so that it stays same.
     }
  }

  func loadWeatherTemp() {
    let forecastConstants = ForecastConstants(apiKey: forecastAPIKey)
    coordinates.latitude = latPassed
    coordinates.longitude = LongPassed

    if latPassed == 0 && LongPassed == 0 {
        coordinates.latitude = 43.161030
        coordinates.longitude = -77.610922
    }
    forecastConstants.getForecast(latitude: coordinates.latitude, longitude: coordinates.longitude) { (currentWeather) in
        if let currentWeather = currentWeather {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

}
Sorry for late reply.
Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "set the new coordinates from MainViewController()". I've already passed them as I included in the code. Please clarify, thank you.

Comment: As you've took a reference of MainForeCastViewController() instead of that make a new object of CLLocationCoordiante2D() as mentioned in my answer in your MapViewController() and in your MainForeCastViewController() take reference of MapViewController() and from there update the coordinates. If you share your MainForeCastViewController() code then i'll explain it with more detail.

Comment: If understand correctly, after creating the newCoordinates object, I will jump back to the MainViewController, where I will be using that object to receive the new coordinates, instead of passing them to the MapViewController? I have added the code from MainViewController.